# Algorithims- Dynamic Programming- Travelling salesman problem

Tags: algorithm

Should the adjacency matrix of the traveling salesman problem be symmetric? What are the problems if it is asymmetric?

Comment: It does not matter, classical DP solution works for both types of matrices

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context of your problem (e.g. if you have one-way streets then a directed graph, asymmetric, makes more sense). Interestingly, the asymmetric case is actually equivalent to the symmetric case by doubling the number of nodes (source: https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/Traveling_salesman_problems#Classifications_of_the_TSP).

Comment: Thank you so much!